# Chromium will not start - libffmpeg problem

Tags: chromium, ffmpeg

When starting chromium-browser from terminal I get:

```
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser: error while loading shared libraries: libffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried reinstalling ffmpeg which didn't work. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Is this your post: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/chromium-libffmpeg-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if you have ffmpeg installed in your system, by typing `which ffmpeg`. If it's there but it's not recognized, it means it's broken and you're gonna have to reinstall it. Try `apt-get --reinstall install ffmpeg`.
That, assuming you didn't compile it yourself, in that case you're gonna have to download a fresh copy of ffmpeg from here http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-2.8.3.tar.bz2, and recompile.

Comment: I run `which ffmpeg` and got `\usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
` Than i did `apt-get -- reinstall install ffmpeg` After which nothing changed. Than i downloaded said file. Unpacked it in /opt and runed `./config` than `make` and `make install` yet it didn't help. Still the same error

Comment: At the last step, try running sudo make install instead, so it will be installed for all users and it'll ensure chromium will recognize it.
Additionally, navigate to the directory `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs/` and do `ls -l`, to see which files are present there and their permissions. libffmpeg.so should be there.

Comment: My bad i didn't write it, i was doing it as a root... (had opend folder in nautilus as administrator and from there i opened terminal which was in root). In `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs/` ther ins not `libffmpeg.so' listed. But then i used ` locate -br ^libffmpeg.so$` and there it was. I made a gist with copy of my terminal. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cc93ae7e5e78710ee31c

Comment: If the file isn't there when performing ls, it means there must be a broken association somewhere. Try `sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg`* and see if that fixes it, if it doesn't let you, add --reinstall to apt-get to force it.
*Fixed the name of the package.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg` solved it. I can use chromium again :) Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, but then I found that chromium location is `/usr/bin/chromium-browser` instead of `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser`

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu the Chromium libfmmpeg.so library (`./usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpeg.so`) is provided by the `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra` package, whose installation was likely corrupted in your case.

In order to solve the problem, you need to reinstall the package:

```
apt-get --reinstall chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

Comment: After installing this, it did not work in my ubuntu: error while loading shared libraries: libffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Still faced this issue in mid 2021 and Linux Mint 20.

The browser seems to start, but then nothing appears.

---

Removing and reinstalling `chromium-browser` **does NOT fix** the issue. Save your time, by not downloading again that insanely thicc installer.

---

Moving the user config, so a new session get created, **does NOT fix** the issue.

```
mv ~/.config/chromium ~/.config/chromium_old
```

Save your time, by not messing up your user config, bookmarks and passwords.

---

By launching from a shell, got the error:

> /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser: error while loading shared
> libraries: **libffmpeg.so**: cannot open shared object file: No such file
> or directory

So, for some reasons, since the **ffmpeg** lib is not found, the browser isn't starting. This is bad, because, a browser update made that, it was working as it is just before.

The fix for me was:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg
```

Then the browser **does start correctly**, even from the desktop launcher.